# How to load Axios Response before Vue Component renders?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to use:

```
homePage.image = 'storage/' + 'rkiGXBj7KJSOtsR5jiYTvNOajnzo7MlRAoXOXe3V.jpg'
```

inside:

```
<div class="home-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + homePage.image + ')'}"></div>
```

before the Vue Component is rendered but `homePage.image` returns `""`.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="home-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + homePage.image + ')'}"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>


<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const homePage = ref({
    image: ""
});

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        homePage.image = 'storage/' + 'rkiGXBj7KJSOtsR5jiYTvNOajnzo7MlRAoXOXe3V.jpg'; // storage link + image file name
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response);
    });

// works
// const image = 'storage/' + 'rkiGXBj7KJSOtsR5jiYTvNOajnzo7MlRAoXOXe3V.jpg';

</script>
```

How do I get `homePage.image` to update to `'storage/' + 'rkiGXBj7KJSOtsR5jiYTvNOajnzo7MlRAoXOXe3V.jpg'` before it is loaded into the Component from inside the `axios` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ref` for reactivity you must use `value`:

```
homePage.value.image = 'storage/' + 'rkiGXBj7KJSOtsR5jiYTvNOajnzo7MlRAoXOXe3V.jpg';
```

Comment: Adding `value` to the assignment made it work. Thank you :-). May I ask what `require` is for? I don't seem to need to add it and it works.

Comment: Hey mate, `require`  you need if you get images from assets directory, in your case you don't need it, so that was my mistake, i will remove it from answer, cheers :)